# Make locales a synonym of locale?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

What about making [locales](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/locales) a synonym of [locale](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/locale)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent idea. Merged!

Comment: Cheers! What is that number ("7654321")?

Comment: @N.N. Posts have to be at least 30 characters long, so I was only at 23 :)

Comment: There is a trick! See the source of my edit.

Comment: ha, I thought about that, but didn't think it would full the SE Engine :)